# ASP.NET MVC - Loading dropdownlists based on selected value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

I have a view that looks somewhat similar to this

```
 <% using (Html.BeginForm()) {%>
    <%= Html.DropDownList("Category") %>
    <%= Html.DropDownList("SubCategory") %>
    <input type="submit" value="Print" />
    <%= Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "Index") %>
<% } %>
```

I was wondering if anyone knew how i could load the subcategory based on the selected Category?
In webforms i'd just use the autopostback event to do this, but i'm a bit confused on how to do this using the mvc framework.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

transform your view like this:

```
 <% using (Html.BeginForm()) {%>
    <%= Html.DropDownList("Category", Model.SelectList, new {onchange = "actualize(this);"}) %>
    <div id="selectdiv">
    <% Html.RenderPartial("SubCategories"); %>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Print" />
    <%= Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "Index") %>
<% } %>

<script type="text/javascript">

function actualize(obj)
{
     $.ajax({
        url: url,
        async: true,
        type: 'POST',
        data: { id: obj.value },
        dataType: 'text',
        success: function(data) { $("#selectdiv").html(data); },
        error: function() {
            console.log('Erreur');
        }
    });
}

</script>
```

create a control called SubCategories.aspx and include in it:

```
<%= Html.DropDownList("SubCategory",Model.SelectList) %>
```

create a Model class

```
public class MyModel
{
    public SelectList SelectList {get;set;}
}
```

create a controller action

```
public ActionResult SubCategories(int id)
{
     MyModel model = new MyModel();
     model.SelectList = new SelectList(YourRepository.GetSubCategories(id),"Id","Name");
     return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Prefer to see the dropdown in a partial view so that it can be re-used.  so instead of having the two dropdowns you could have a single partial view.  makes styling a little easier and you only need to do things once.  i know this is a little redundant with a single dropdown but in my experiance this then becomes second nature with bigger reuasable componants

Comment: If you read, the second drop down is in a partial view called SubCategories.aspx :)

Comment: If there was another drop down after sub categories which depended both on categories and subcategories would you recommend placing that in another partial view as well?

Comment: Nice code. You can see here another way to do the same http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2008/09/07/asp-net-mvc-tip-41-creating-cascading-dropdown-lists-with-ajax.aspx and http://www.michaeljbaird.com/post/2009/04/13/ASPnet-MVC-and-JQuery-Cascading-Droplist.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Place the dropdown list within a PartialView.  Then when you post back do a return PartialView("viewName", model).  Then in the return of your jQuery simply replace the partial view with the new html that is returned.

So you're view;

```
<div id="myPartialView">
  <% Html.PartialView("PartialViewName", model); %>
</div>
```

Then your jQuery does something like

```
$('#myPartialView').html = retHtml;
```

Your C#

```
return PartialView("PartialViewName", model);
```

Untested but that's the approach i think you want to take.